# Open Cart - Get the product id of a product option - sql

Tags: sql, opencart, product

Brand spanking new to Open Cart. I'm trying to do some data exporting.

All I need is the product id of each product option. It doesn't sound complicated but I honestly can't figure out how open cart knows what option is what product.

Example product option:

[image]

I've attached an image of what I'm talking about. You can see that after the product option in square brackets is the ID of the product. But I just can't figure out how Open Cart is associating the option to the product.

The end goal is to get a list of all product_ids that are being used as options and what products they are assigned to (non-required only).

So something like this:

```
select pov.*
from product_option_value pov
where pov.option_id in (select option_id from product_option
                        where required = 0 and price > 0);
```

If product_option_value actually had the `product_id` of the option in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone else needs to do this - I figured it out eventually.

```
SELECT pov.product_id, substring_index(substring_index(ovd.name, '[', -1),']', 1) as option_product_id, p.model
FROM product_option_value pov
LEFT JOIN option_value ov
ON pov.option_value_id = ov.option_value_id
LEFT JOIN option_value_description ovd
ON ov.option_value_id = ovd.option_value_id
LEFT JOIN product p
ON p.product_id = pov.product_id
WHERE ovd.name LIKE '%[%'
AND ovd.name NOT LIKE '%FREE%'
AND pov.option_id IN (SELECT option_id FROM product_option WHERE required = 0);
```

Most of this is pretty straight forward. I'm using some likes to only get product options with product ids. I use a substring within a substring in the select to get everything between the square brackets.

This gives us a list of options and the product ids they are assigned to

( i don't have enough rep for an image so here ascii instead)

```
+------------+-------------------+-------+
| product_id | option_product_id | model |
+------------+-------------------+-------+
|       1234 |               223 | mmss1 |
|       1234 |               224 | mmss1 |
|       1225 |               221 | mmss3 |
|       1226 |               229 | mmss6 |
+------------+-------------------+-------+
```

So for example product 1234 has two options, their product ids are 223 and 224

If anyone finds a better way of doing this rather than ripping product ids out of a name column please let me know as this feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.. I assume that you are having a product table and you have to display the optionID against each product..

```
SELECT pd.ProductName+'['+Convert(VARCHAR(50),po.option_id)+']',.....
FROM product_option_value pov
    JOIN product pd on pd pov.product_id=pd.product_id
    JOIN product_option po on po.option_id=pov.option_id
WHERE po.required = 0 and po.price > 0
```

Comment: I'm afraid not. The product id inside square brackets is not added to the name of the product in the database. It's just a frontend feature. However, I don't actually have the codebase in order to reverse engineer it. I'm hoping for someone who is familiar with OpenCart DB architecture.